# Alfalfa Sprouts on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

If you are consuming alfalfa sprouts directly from the container they were grown in would it be an issue of kotzer to consume them on Shabbos?

There are two types I have seen

1. Homegrown - is done in containers but no soil is involved it grows with water moisture
2. Alfalfa from the store come in plastic containers I am not sure if they are sprouted in these containers or are sprouted elsewhere and then transferred

If kotzer only applies where the food is removed from soil or another [nutrient source](https://www.ou.org/holidays/melacha-3-reaping/) maybe both would be ok.
#2 is really more of a technical question on how store bought sprouts are grown/harvested

Comment: to guide those providing answers, this is essentially a question of whether there is kotzer in an atzitz she'eino nakuv. Here is where it IS a perforated container. https://aish.com/5-kotzer-from-the-ground-up/ and where it is not: https://etzion.org.il/he/halakha/orach-chaim/shabbat/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-2